# Lambda "select between"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generic string list that looks something like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("foo");
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("bar");
list.Add("foo");
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("3");
list.Add("bar");
```

What I would like to know is if there is any way to select whats between two values. In this case I'm after "1", "2" and "3". So in other words, i want to select everything between the last "foo" and "bar". Or perhaps select N rows after "foo" if that's easier.

My best guess would be the `TakeWhile` method, but I need your help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the *last* ones is usually a little trickier with LINQ. I'd just go for `LastIndexOf` for that part, since you have a `List`, after all:

```
int end = list.LastIndexOf("foo");

list.Skip(end + 1).TakeWhile(x => x != "bar")
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to use "StartsWith" method here? So that i get all lines starting with "foo"?

Comment: @Johan: You'd use `FindLastIndex` instead of `LastIndexOf`, as seen in Eugene's answer: `int end = list.FindLastIndex(x => x.StartsWith("foo"));`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this (if "bar" is not always present after "foo"):

```
var start = list.FindLastIndex(i => i == "foo");
var end = list.FindLastIndex(i => i == "bar");

if(start != -1 && end != -1){
    var result = list.Skip(start + 1).Take(end - start - 1);
}
```

Or this:

```
var start = list.FindLastIndex(i => i == "foo");
var end = list.FindLastIndex(i => i == "bar");

if(start != -1 && end != -1){
    var result = list.GetRange(start + 1, end - start - 1);
}
```